# DB2, special character occupies 2 bytes

Tags: insert, db2

I have a problem inserting special characters (á é í ú or ñ) in a char(1) field.

```
CREATE TABLE sgc2."tabtest2"(field1 CHAR(1), field2 VARCHAR(1));
INSERT INTO sgc2."tabtest2" values('á', 'á');
```

ERROR:

`Value "á" is too long.. SQLCODE=-433, SQLSTATE=22001, DRIVER=4.13.111`

Apparently to insert these characters take two byte, and as the field only accepts one can not end with the insertion.
Is there any way to configure the database, to support these special characters taking only 1 byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your database was created with the Unicode codeset, where special characters are represented by multiple bytes. If you only need to represent a limited range of accented characters you can choose one of the supported codesets, specified by ISO-8859, for the corresponding language -- details [in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html). You will have to re-create the database using an appropriate `CODESET` option, as you cannot change the codeset of an existing database.

However, you should consider changing your tables instead, as Unicode gives you more flexibility. A Unicode database can also be a requirement for certain DB2 features, for example BLU Acceleration.

Comment: `Apparently your database was created...` -- "was created"? or "was not created"?

Comment: Was created. DB2 will automatically translate between the client codeset and the database codeset. Since the OP observes that accented characters like "á" won't fit into the `CHAR(1)` column it's safe to assume that they become multibyte characters on the database side, which would happen if the database was created with a Unicode codeset.

Comment: Couldn't he also change the column definition from CHAR(1) to NCHAR(1) which would support the single multi-byte unicode characters?

Comment: It's possible but then, instead of relying on automatic charset conversion by the DB2 driver it would become the responsibility of the application to supply the correctly encoded values.

Comment: I finally had to re-create the database.
With the following characteristics of the
Table 39 of [this manual.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.nls.doc/doc/r0004565.html)